# Opposite direction of rotating vectors in DFT

Tags: fourier-transform, computational-mathematics, fast-fourier-transform

I was following up with this website: https://www.instructables.com/Drawing-With-Discrete-Fourier-Transform/
The idea is to take some sample points from a path drawn, use DFT algorithm to convert it into equal number of vectors with certain amplitude, phase change and frequency. I don't get why some of the vectors are rotating clockwise while others are rotating anticlockwise since the $\text{angle component} = \text{freq}\cdot \text{time} + \text{phase change}$ Time is the same for all vectors and positive, and frequency is also positive.